# Could not pass the username password for FTP command from linux

Tags: linux, ftp

I need to connect to a Remote FTP host via linux command line. When I try `#ftp <IP address>`, it prompts for username then password.. But I would like to pass username and password in single line, so remote host should not prompt username or password..

I tried passing as `#ftp <ip address> <pw.cfg>`, but no success. May I know the command how to pass username and password along with IP address to FTP remote host.. Ideally i will be using this command from a linux script.

`pw.cfg`: text file contains password

Comment: Don't use ftp, especially over the internet. You are passing passwords in the clear. Either use scp or sftp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.netrc` file in your home directory. In the file enter record like:

```
machine machine_name user username password your_password
```

and when you enter:

```
ftp machine_name
```

`ftp` will user `user_name` to login and `your_password` as password

Comment: Thanks that works charm..I used as machine IP login LOGINUSER password PASSWORD123